# how to split data by IF

Tags: excel

i need know to know how

- i can add many rows as every time i write in Cell A3 the split data go to row 5 only but i need it go to the row 6 then 7 and so on
- i can make 2 conditions:

  1. if the cell A3 content number that number is start with "0" transfer to number column "column E" E5
  2. if the Cell A3 content (( *.com or *.net )) that word transfer to product column "column B" B5
- how i can add more delimiters like (//,/,-)?

```
Sub SplitText1()

Const SourceRange = "A3" ' <-- Source data range, change to suit
Const DestCell = "a5"       ' <-- First destination cell, change to suit

Dim a As Variant, cell As Range, i As Long

For Each cell In Range(SourceRange)
a = split(cell.Value, "//")

ReDim Preserve a(0 To 6)
If Val(a(3)) = a(3) Then
  a(4) = a(3)
  a(3) = Empty
End If
Range(DestCell).Offset(i).Resize(, 6).Value = a
i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Maybe you should try to write it in a form of a question, or several separate questions.

Comment: i write line of data in Cell A3 which contents some data like name,website,contact number 
"A // *.com // 09999999" 
i need to split  any data content *.com to be in a certain Cell like : B5